# Content Porter 2009 SP2 failing to import a publication

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I have been Content Porting a project successfully until I reached the final publication, which is giving me an error. The import only gets to the preparing package phase when it fails and returns 'Unable to load Package Item's xml'. I am running Tridion SP1 with Content Porter SP2.

I have tried re-exporting to ensure that the file was not corrupted somehow, I have also tried exporting the publication individually and also with another publication. When I imported the file with both publications, the other publication imported flawlessly while the publication that had been giving me problems still failed with the same error. Any ideas?

```
7/9/2013 1:16:08 PM [Critical]  Unable to load Package Item's xml.   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Packaging.PackageItem.set_ItemXml(String value)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Packaging.Package.GetItem(WebDavUrl url)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Packaging.Package.AddItemToTemporaryPackage(Item item, Package temporaryPackage, List`1 selectedItems, List`1 dependencyFilters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Packaging.Package.AddItemToTemporaryPackage(Item item, Package temporaryPackage, List`1 selectedItems, List`1 dependencyFilters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Packaging.Package.ApplyFilter(List`1 dependencyFilters, List`1 selectedItems, XmlDocument editedMappingsXml, ProgressChangedEventHandler handler, BackgroundWorker worker)
   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Models.ContentPorterModel.CreateTemporaryPackage(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Models.ContentPorterModel.OnDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
```

Comment: Will you provide package ?

Comment: It looks like it's breaking on a particular item and we need to figure out which one.  Make sure that you set logging options to "Log Everything".  Maybe we can get an ID or webdav path or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience with Content Porter it's nearly always something to do with Keywords...

Double check your keywords and schemas have been imported into the correct level - (I'm assuming when you say you broke the export/import into chunks you mean schema/keywords, then design, then content, then website levels etc.)...

Check you don't have any local keywords that have a dependancy on a higher level category that doesn't exist - from memory I think this throws a 'not-so-clear' error.